# Access Spinner from another class

Tags: android, spinner, android-spinner

I have a spinner created in the onCreate function. Here is the code:

```
    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                this, R.array.weight_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new MyOnItemSelectedListener());
```

Now I want to access the spinner from another class. What I want to do is set the spinner selection to position 0 when I am done with a method. I reckon I have to use something like:

```
    spinner.setselection(0);
```

but doing this outside the class where the spinner was created doesn't work. Here is the section of code where I'm trying to access the spinner:

```
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) 
{
    switch(item) 
    {
        case 0:
        {
            float valueInput = Float.parseFloat(valueEntered.getText().toString());
                    valueEntered.setText(String.valueOf(convertKilosToGrams(valueInput)));
                    ///This is where i want to to access the spinner///
             break;
         }
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to define an interface, with a function `DoSomethingToSpinner` and then implement it in your main activity

```
public void DoSomethingToSpinner (some_parameter)
{
     spinner.setselection(some_parameter);
     // do your work here

}
```

and then call `interface.DoSomethingToSpinner` and it should solve your problem.

Comment: I create the spinner in the onCreate class. so where can i can add the method?

Comment: it doesn't let me add a method in the onCreate class. what can i add as the parameter?

Comment: Edited, check answer, it won't allow to change parameters of onClick either

Comment: how do i define an interface? and what do i use as a parameter, where you state "some parameter"?

Comment: This some parameter depends on your implementation, what you want to do with the spinner, such as the value for spinner.setselection(<some parameter>);

Comment: not working for me. dont exaclty know how to implement your solution. im having trouble with the interface. it doesnt let me create the interface.

Comment: the problem is when i create the interface with the DoSomethingToSpinner function and write spinner.setSelection(0), it cant access spinner because spinner is not within the method.

Comment: Get it using findViewById, or create a global spinner, assign the spinner to it in onCreate

Answer (score 0):

To apply @SpeedBirdNine's answer to the problem. You need to make your class package-accessible. To do this, you can add

```
private MyClass instance;
```

to your class, then initialize it with

```
instance = this;
```

in `onCreate()`. You also need a static method to access the Activity, as

```
static Activity getInstance() { return instance; }
```

so that you can call

```
Activity.getInstance().DoSomethingToSpinner(parameter);
```

#### More accessible

To make this even more accessible, you can define the static function

```
static void doSomethingToSpinner(parameter) {
    getInstance().DoSomethingToSpinner(parameter);
}
```

which can be accessed from anywhere.

#### Just give me the Spinner

If you want to access the Spinner object to just "do stuff" with it (which is discouraged), you can use

```
static Spinner getSpinner() { return getInstance().getSpinnerMember(); }
```

with

```
Spinner getSpinnerMember() { return spinner; }
```

This provides the calling class with access to the whole Spinner object, thus does not protect from unintended errors by package objects.

#### Explanation

The other class has no handle on the Activity containing the Spinner. As there is only one instance of the activity at a time, you can save a global handle in `onCreate`. This can then provide access to its spinner object.